# How do you add Identity server 4.0 as an external provider?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

It looks like all of the sources talk about adding external providers INTO Identity Server 4, not using Identity Server 4 AS an external provider.

My startup.cs has this line for Facebook authentication:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               
            })
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                 facebookOptions.AppId = "<appId>";
                 facebookOptions.AppSecret = "<appSecret>";
                 facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;

             })
```

I have a button on my login page:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"
   asp-action="ExternalLogin"
   asp-route-provider="Facebook"
   asp-route-returnUrl="">
    Facebook
</a>
```

Which leads to:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

Which all works.
I also have an Identity Server 4.0 server setup and I would like to use it as just another external provider.

```
            services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                 facebookOptions.AppId = "<appId>";
                 facebookOptions.AppSecret = "<appSecret>";
                 facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;

             })
            .AddIdentityServer(identityServerOptions=> //Doesn't exist? or Does it?
            {
                 identityServerOptions.AppId = "<appId>";
                 identityServerOptions.AppSecret = "<appSecret>";
                 identityServerOptions.SaveTokens = true;

             })
```

**How do I add identity server as an external auth provider?**

**UPDATE: **
From [This site](https://damienbod.com/2018/08/15/implementing-a-multi-tenant-oidc-azure-ad-external-login-for-identityserver4/)

```
@if (Model.ExternalProviders.Any())
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalProviders)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a class="btn btn-default"
                           asp-action="ExternalLogin"
                           asp-route-provider="@provider.AuthenticationScheme"
                           asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
                            @provider.DisplayName
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It looks like the provider is the same as the Authentication Scheme

Answer (score 0):

Identityserver is a certified OpenId Connect provider, so you can use just:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(authenticationScheme, displayName, options =>
{
  options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
  options.Authority = "<base-path-of-your-external-IS>";
  options.ClientSecret = "<appSecret>";
  options.ClientId = "<appId>";
  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
  options.SaveTokens = true;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Do you know the provider name I would use with _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

Comment: maybe you don't need SignInManager at all? if all you need is just create an auth cookie (based in external auth) and save the tokens, it will work without ASP.Net Core Identity and Entity Framework. You just perform the challenge (redirect to external IdP) and then handle the callback (call HttpContext.SignInAsync()). more or less that's all.

Comment: If you still need to involve the ASP.Net Core Identity, you are right, use the same name you preferred for the authenticationScheme